# check x509 Certificate validity

Tags: flutter, x509

I would like to check validity of a certificate x509 in flutter like this js method.

```
import tls from 'tls';
import { X509Certificate } from 'crypto'

function validCertificate(cert, key) {
  try {
    tls.createSecureContext({ cert, key })
    const { validTo } = new X509Certificate(cert);
    return new Date(validTo) > new Date()
  }
  catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'ERR_OSSL_X509_KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH') {
      return false;
    }
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Parse the cert using the basic_utils package - see https://pub.dev/packages/basic_utils#x509utils - and compare the date.

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing around to get some data from pem cert, and ended up writing this snip

```
var v = utils.X509Utils.x509CertificateFromPem(directpemstring);
            print(v.tbsCertificate!.validity.notAfter);
```